# Arch linux: Failed to mount /boot

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, systemd-boot

when I try to start uo my system I get this error:

```
[Failed] Failed to mount /boot
See 'systemctl status boot.mount' for details
[DEPEND] Dependency filed for Local File System
```

then some more logs and

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, or "exit" to continue bootup.

Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to contienue
```

What can i do to fix it ? I am not able to log in to mu system but I am able to run run `arch-chroot` from live USB.

Edit: this in `systemctl status boot.mount`

```
mount: /boot: unknown file system 'vfat'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happened

I used `arch-chroot` on live usb to install networkmanager and I updated all packages in process. The linux kernel updated as well and installed `initframs` to `/boot` but boot partition was not mounted. This created situation where on boot partitions were files associated with different kernel version.

#### Solution

I solved it by:

1. Booting live arch
2. chroting into system
3. creating another boot dir `mkdir /tmp/boot`
4. mounting boot partition `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /tmp/boot`
5. Moving boot files to right place `mv /boot/* /tmp/boot`
6. exit chroot
7. reboot